# How to get Distinct rows in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4

I have 6 Records in following Table

[image]

I Need to get Unique Leads id Columns Order by id DESC.

Following is my Query

```
Telecallerfirststep::WhereDate('created_at',date('Y-m-d'))->groupBy('leadsid')->OrderBy('id','DESC')->count();
```

Its Return Number of Records is : 1

Comment: just add `->distinct()`

Comment: WhereDate(Date('created_at'),date('Y-m-d'))

Comment: did check by changing  `WhereDate` to `whereDate` ?

Comment: Laravel: where every query looks like a [train wreck](http://wiki.c2.com/?TrainWreck)

Answer (score 0):

```
Just Add distinct

Telecallerfirststep::WhereDate('created_at',date('Y-m-d'))-
>groupBy('leadsid')->OrderBy('id','DESC')->distinct()->count();
```

Comment: Its Return Only 2 Records(521, 1315 - Leads ids). I need 4 Records(52, 1510 - Leads ids also).

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
Telecallerfirststep::whereDate('created_at','=',date('Y-m-d'))->groupBy('leadsid')->count();
```

Comment: Its Return All Records @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd

Comment: @Karthik: Let me check

Comment: Its Return Only 2 Records(521, 1315 - Leads ids). I need 4 Records(52, 1510 - Leads ids also).

Comment: @Karthik: please check my updated answer and let me know this updated answer work for you or not

Comment: Its Return Only 1 Record @AddWeb Solution Pvt Ltd

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158832/discussion-between-addweb-solution-pvt-ltd-and-karthik).

Answer (score 0):

Use php `count` after fetching result

```
$reault = Telecallerfirststep::whereDate('created_at',date('Y-m-d'))->groupBy('leadsid')->OrderBy('id','DESC'); 
echo $count = count($reault);
```

I found similar issue [MySql](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=26209) and [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28651727/laravel-eloquent-distinct-and-count-not-working-properly-together)