# Group same date and count together

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, count, grouping

I have done a code to call an array of a value based on each date. My code is below:

```
$matchs = DiraChatLog::where('status','=','Match')->whereBetween('date_access', [$request->from, $request->to])->get();
$array[] = [];
foreach ($matchs as $key => $match) {
    $array[$match->date_access] = $match->status;
}

dd($array);
```

Using this I try and `dd();` I get output like this:
[image]

What I'm trying to do now is to first group the same dates together and also I want to then count the total for that dates. how can I do this?

Comment: Did you try: `distinct('date_field')->count('date_field')` ?

Comment: @EazySam no i have not.. how should i write that?

Comment: attach distinct() and count() with the query. What was the name of the date field?

Comment: `$matchs = DiraChatLog::where('status','=','Match')->whereBetween('date_access', [$request->from, $request->to])->distinct('date_access')->count('date_access')->get();dd($matchs);`-what do you get from this code?

Comment: this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28651727/laravel-eloquent-distinct-and-count-not-working-properly-together

Comment: its "date_access" @EazySam

Comment: @EazySam i get an error `
FatalThrowableError in PreBuiltController.php line 612:
Call to a member function get() on integer`

Comment: Is that working without `get()`?

Comment: without get, i get this error `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

Comment: That is because you get the **count of distinct items** there. `dd($matchs);`. Now `groupBy` with another query or use logic inside PHP iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you mean with "date". But if you mean the same day it would be this:

```
$matchs = DiraChatLog::where('status','=','Match')->whereBetween('date_access', [$request->from, $request->to])->get();
$array[] = [];
foreach ($matchs as $key => $match) {
 $day = substr($match->date_access, 0, 10);
 if(isset($array[$day])){
  $array[$day]++;
 }else{
  $array[$day] = 1;
 }
}

dd($array);
```

Comment: this worked for me thanks! Also one more things, how can i declare this array to "match" that means i wanna call it match. so instead of dd(array); i wanna dd($match); ?

Comment: if you want to do this you need to first rename all $match (variable already exists in your code!) to another name. then you rename all $array to $match. but this is really the most basic issue. i recommend you to read a view tutorials about php basics.

Answer (score 0):

```
   $array= array();
   $arrayCount=array();
   foreach ($matchs as $key => $match) { 
       $time = strtotime($match->date_access); 
       $newformat = date('Y-m-d',$time);
       if(!array_key_exists($newformat , $array)){ 
                 $i=1;
            $array[$newformat]=$match->status; 
       }     

            //$array[$newformat]=$i;   remove this comment if you want the count inside
            $arrayCount[$newformat]=$i;
            $i++;
     }
```

in the event you want to maintain the "match" value in your array if not just un-comment the code and remover $arrayCount occurrences

Comment: i get an error of `FatalThrowableError in PreBuiltController.php line 623:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '++' (T_INC)`

Comment: ohh sorry i meat $i updating anwer

Comment: check its updated  been writhing java  forgot about $var in php

Comment: i still get an error `ErrorException in PreBuiltController.php line 621:
Use of undefined constant i - assumed 'i'`

Comment: check var_dump($arrayCount )   it has the date and how many occurrences were there