# Laravel Eloquent Equivalent for MYSQL DISTINCT query multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent, distinct

Is there an equivalent query for this in eloquent?

```
 SELECT DISTINCT agent_code,ord_amount FROM orders
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel Eloquent - distinct() and count() not working properly together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28651727/laravel-eloquent-distinct-and-count-not-working-properly-together)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```php
Order::select('agent_code', 'ord_amount')->distinct()->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this eloquent query:

```
$orders = Order::select('agent_code', 'ord_amount')->distinct()->orderBy('agent_code')->get();
```